# Printing a Tic-Tac-Toe board in Ruby

Tags: ruby, comparative-review, tic-tac-toe

I have two implementations of a function that prints out a basic board for Tic-Tac-Toe.

Which of these should I include and why?

```
def display_board(board)
  for i in 0...9
    print " #{ board[i] }"
    if (i+1)%3 != 0
      print " |"
    elsif i != 9
       print " \n#{'-'*11}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

```
def display_board(board)
  puts " #{board[0]} | #{board[1]} | #{board[2]} "
  puts "-----------"
  puts " #{board[3]} | #{board[4]} | #{board[5]} "
  puts "-----------"
  puts " #{board[6]} | #{board[7]} | #{board[8]} "
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely version two.

- It makes no use of control structures such as `for` or `if`, it has very low [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) because of that, and it is good, as it is directly related to difficulty in understanding.
- It lets you see in a single glance what the output will look like.

Comment: Without even understanding the code, I have a visceral attraction to the 2nd version and a repulsion to the first, a reaction that occurs in well under half a second.  It's interesting how often these gut reactions to the visual appearance of code turn out to be a correct assessment of readability and other more rigorous complexity metrics.

Comment: @Jonah I also had that sensation in less than a second, but half a second after I though "What about extensibility?" promptly followed by "Tic-Tac-Tac is only ever 3x3 so extensibility is not a problem".

Comment: Yeah, I think it's great mini-lesson in the costs of abstraction, and a reminder to think about the likely changes in your domain, and know when making something brittle but simple is the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to pick, I'd take the second version. Not that the first approach is bad, it just needs a refactor. I'd write:

```
def display_board(board)
  puts board.each_slice(3).map { |row| row.join(" | ") }.join("\n" + "-"*11 + "\n")
end
```